# C# GetAwaiter async Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to using await/async and I have a basic question.  I was able to successfully implement the await/async model in my WebApi Controller and the Business Object (BL) for deletes so in the BL on the `Delete` method I invoke `await entities.SaveChangesAsync();` and updated the method's signature to return `public static async Task<ProfileItem> Delete(int profileId, int profileItemId)` and this works!!!

Now, I want to do the same when I "fetch" data, so, I have a "getter" and I update the method's signature to `public static async Task<List<Property>> GetProperties(int userId, int userTypeId)` and here I have some logic that (1) uses the entity framework to retrieve a result set, then I do some stuff and convert my EntityObject into a BusinessObject and return a `List<Property>`, however when I do `return await ...` I get the error: List does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method ...

Here's the code

```
public static async Task<List<Property>> GetProperties(int userId, int userTypeId)
    {

        entities = new MyEntities();

        var userType = entities.sl_USER_TYPE.Where(_userType => _userType.ID == userTypeId).First();


        var properties = entities.sl_PROPERTY.Where(_property => _property.USER_ID == userId && _property.USER_TYPE_ID == userTypeId);

        if (!properties.Any())
            throw new Exception("Error: No Properties exist for this user!");

        // here is where I get the error
        return await ConvertEntiesToBusinessObj(properties.ToList(), userId);

    }
```

What do I need to do to be able to access the benefits of this functionality in this case.  Basically I can use Task/async for Saving information to the DB but not getting.  I am sure it is my lack of understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue is in `ConvertEntiesToBusinessObj`. Please show the code for that method.

Comment: `var list = await properties.ToListAsync(); if(list.Count==0) { throw new Exception("Error: No Properties exist for this user!"); } else { return ConvertEntiesToBusinessObj(list, userId); }`. If you going to retrieve elements anyway, then no need to do separate `Any()` call. Also, you can use `await FirstAsync()` instead of `First()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `await` on "awaitables", which for the most part means `Task` or `Task<T>`.

`ConvertEntiesToBusinessObj` does not return `Task<T>`, which is fine. It sounds like a synchronous method, so it shouldn't.

What you want to do is use `ToListAsync` instead of `ToList`, and `await` that:

```
return ConvertEntiesToBusinessObj(await properties.ToListAsync(), userId);
```

Also, as PetSerAI pointed out, it would be more efficient to use `ToListAsync` once, rather than `Any` followed by `ToList`/`ToListAsync`:

```
public static async Task<List<Property>> GetProperties(int userId, int userTypeId)
{
  entities = new MyEntities();
  var userType = await entities.sl_USER_TYPE.Where(_userType => _userType.ID == userTypeId).FirstAsync();
  var properties = await entities.sl_PROPERTY.Where(_property => _property.USER_ID == userId && _property.USER_TYPE_ID == userTypeId).ToListAsync();

  if (!properties.Any())
    throw new Exception("Error: No Properties exist for this user!");

  return ConvertEntiesToBusinessObj(properties, userId);
}
```

The general rule to follow here is to **not** approach `async` with the mindset of "I want to make this function async; how do I do this?". The appropriate approach is to first identify naturally-asynchronous operations (generally I/O-based) - in this example, the EF queries. Then make *those* asynchronous and call them with `await`, and allow `async`/`await` to grow naturally from there.